# Uploading files from compute engine to cloud storage php-javascript

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

We're migrating our code onto compute engine at the moment and are struggling to understand file uploading from php.  Need a little nudge in the right direction from a pro.

We're moving our servers to Compute Engine and need customers to be able to upload files from our site to google cloud storage.  I don't know what the best way is to do this, maybe javascript, maybe php?  PHP would require the least changes to our current code.

How do we upload files from a PHP application to Cloud Storage when hosted on Compute Engine?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Going to get a support package but we're just in the testing phase at the moment.

Comment: You probably want to use the [Google PHP API Library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), and specifically `src/Google/Service/Storage.php`.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasOrozco, that's great.  Do you know if there is any documentation or examples of using this Storage API?  I can't quite figure out how to upload a file.  I'm sure I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: There's example code in the same project (under `examples`). Nothing specific to Cloud Storage, unfortunately, but it should be easy enough to transpose by simply looking at the Google Cloud Storage JSON API documentation.

Comment: @robwithhair have you figured this out? Definitely interested in your solution

Comment: Unfortunately via the php api library, that's all that's available.  Or you can use curl directly.  Because PHP isn't multithreaded this can be really slow with lots of files.  Could do with a C php extension for this from google really.  We're migrating out codebase to python because of this and lots of other annoyances.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the supported methods for uploading files to Google Cloud Storage via PHP here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload

Comment: Uploading via compute engine, not app engine.  We will eventually migrate to app engine but for now it's compute engine.  Thanks anyway for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

here is good sample from google
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-getting-started-php